# Add to Slack - MS Bot framework - he Bot Directory is no longer accepting new submissions

Tags: botframework, slack

I am enabling slack channel in MS bot framework. All mentioned steps are done and from my own ID i am able to communicate with bot.
However, I when I give "Add to Slack" button to another slack user, it asks for permissions. After allowing the permission, the user is transferred to https://bots.botframework.com/ webpage where following is written: 
Persmissions snapshot: [Permissions snapshot before bot framework page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ibur.png)
[error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCyFJ.png)

**The Bot Directory is no longer accepting new submissions. Add your bot to the Bing channel so users will not only be able to find it, but chat with it too**

I have already enabled bot for public in slack settings, and users should be able to chat with bot who have the ID of bot.

Looks like some change has been done from Microsoft, which I am not aware of. Ideally it should take the user to conversation page

Comment: "However, I when I give "Add to Slack" button to another slack user, it asks for permissions" : why are you doing that? Adding to Slack must be done only my the admin, then it can be used by other people

Comment: I have added a snapshot of permissions [https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ibur.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ibur.png)
Are you talking about some other permissions page? permission in snapshot comes only after enabling by admin

Comment: "However, I when I give "Add to Slack" button to another slack user, it asks for permissions" : why are you doing that?

Comment: I want my bot built on Bot framework to be available for selected slack users, That is why I am using "Add to slack" or "Sign in slack" button. Is that correct?

Comment: Even when I tried to install the app manually to other workspace I am taken to same botframework page: https://xxx.slack.com/apps/xxAPPID-xxxAPPNAME?next_id=0

Comment: Hi user! I think what he means is: are you adding other people for admin purposes, so they can make changes and what not, or are you trying to add people just so they can talk to the bot?

Comment: @JJ_Wailes: Thanks for looking into this. I want other users to chat with the bot. No admin functionality is required for other slack users. Bot should just get added to their workspace for chatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for user to chat with your bot on Slack, you DO NOT need to use that link to connect them. The method you're attempting is to give them a roundabout admin access, which won't actually work.

In order for your users to communicate with your bot, once it's properly connected to Slack, they can simply select it on the app list, like so:

[image: slack app list]

Additionally, you as the admin, can add the bot to a particular channel, where the users can chat with the bot directly.

[image: gamebot chat]

Comment: Thanks for reply. You have suggested to pick the bot from app list. However, I am not publishing bot to the Slack app store. Mine is an enterprise bot, which can not simply be available to all slack users worldwide.

Comment: If your users are connected to the same slack workspace, they'll be able to connect with your bot just fine. The human talking to the bot above (Ashely) is a coworker of mine. She isn't a listed admin of the bot, and the bot isn't on the app store.

Comment: In your case multiple users (including the bot) are connected to same workspace. Can I conclude, that a bot can not be attached to another workspace without publishing to the store? Or still there may be some option? Are you aware of any support email ID where I can send this question?

Comment: I, as the bot dev, put the bot on the workspace I'm attached to. AFAIK, if you want to put it on a SECOND (or more) workspace, then you're gonna have to put it on the store, yes. But that's a slack specific question, moreso then a bot framework one, and you can get support for slack apps here: https://api.slack.com/support

Comment: Sandeep B wrote: *Along with answer supplied by JJ_Wailes ... just to mention that the error that was mentioned in question is a static reply from Microsoft page. That is meant to be ignored. The bot integration was actually successful.*